# Mongoose nested array update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hey folks this is how my schema looks.

```
const socialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Entry_Number: Number,
    Player_Name: String,
    Player_Message : String,
    Player_Fullmessage: String,
    Player_ProfilePic : String,
    Player_UploadedPic: String,
    Player_UploadedVideos: String,
    Status_Date: String,
    Status_Feeling: String,
    Google_Profile: String,
    Status_Likes: [{Like_Number: Number, Liked_By: String}],
    Status_Comments: [{ 
                        Comment_Number: Number,
                        Comment_By: String,
                        Comment_Message: String,
                        replies: [
                          {Comment_By: String,
                           Comment_Message: String}
                        ]
                     }],
    Friends: { type: Array, default: []},
    Shares: { type: Array, default: []},
    Shared_Post: String,
    Shared_Newmessage: String,
    Shared_PostDetails: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "socialdatas"}]
});
```

I am trying to update the replies nested array inside the Status_Comments array, from values coming from the front end.Here is where I am after multiple tries.

```
socialRegister.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.hiddentextcommentid3, "Status_Comments._id": req.body.hiddentextcommentid3a},
                                                                                {$push: {"Status_Comments.$.replies":
                                                                                              {
                                                                                                  "Comment_By": req.user.Player_Name,
                                                                                                  "Comment_Message" : req.body.replymessage
                                                                                              }}}, function(err,data1)
```

I dont get any error on my terminal, but there is no update happening also. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
let reply = {
              "Comment_By": req.user.Player_Name,
              "Comment_Message" : req.body.replymessage
            }
socialRegister.findOneAndUpdate({"Status_Comments._id":req.body.hiddentextcommentid3a},
                                {$push: {"Status_Comments.$.replies": reply }},{new: true},
                                (err,data) =>{
                                          console.log(data)
                                 })
```

Comment: can you check if you can fetch something with `find({"Status_Comments._id":req.body.hiddentextcommentid3a})`

Comment: yep i can Karl..Just ran a simple findOne query in node and the expected record is getting displayed

Comment: @SandeepNair, see the updated code, with new : true

Comment: no man, tried other combinations also,,,,I am gonna pick it up again tomorrow...if you have any other ideas do let me know and thanks so much bud,,very rare that someone in stack helps a newbie like this...appreciate it

Comment: @SandeepNair , ill come up with other ways tomorrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219775/discussion-between-karl-l-and-sandeep-nair).